# Login meteor web application with SSO

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I need to implement SSO login functionality in meteor web application where the third party services  providers are not going to be like some facebook, google, github...etc, I have my own application to handle all user and privileges details.

Used `express.js`, `node.js` along with packages like passport and open-clientId to authenticate my application. I got the expected user info result.

Now I tried the same using meteor framework. Didn't find any supporting packages. So I just used express, express-session, passport and open-clientId inside meteor server and  integrated express to meteor like the below code..

```
var app = express();
WebApp.connectHandlers.use(app);
```

and used the below route for login :

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('oidc'));
```

Its working and i got the user info.

Since I am not using account packages for login. Meteor not going to have user logging details.

And also I am using Flow Router and Blaze render for handling routing,  so I unable to handle authentication for several other pages.

I would like to know is there any way to handle our own service configuration for SSO other than the oauth package and account package with supporting service providers. Do any one have idea about this?

Comment: There are some packages for SSO and AD SSO, have a look at this thread for some pointers. https://forums.meteor.com/t/simple-single-sign-on-sso-solution-in-meteor/2689/9